# debug mode transaction managed differently

Tags: java, entitymanager

I want to remove an object from a list with a specific sql statement.
Example: a dossier containing a list of message.

I want that after removing a message, the list is automatically refresh. It's the case but when I launch my application with the Remote Java Application I have to manually refresh the dossier with the entity manager. I was wondering why there is such difference when I want to debug the code.

I use weblogic as application server.

Thanks.

```
BenefitDossier dossier = dossierRepo.getDossierByDossierId(dossierIdentifier, CREATED);

// perform the removing
messageRepository.removeOrUpdateMessagesFromDossier(dossier.getDossierId(), COMPLETENESS_RECOGNITION);

dossierRepo.refresh(dossier); // need to add this statement only in debug mode

return dossier;


@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dmb-jta")
protected EntityManager em;

public void removeOrUpdateMessagesFromDossier(DisBenMessageCategory category, String dossierNr) {
    if (category.preserveHistory()) {
        updateMessagesRemovalTimestamp(category, dossierNr);
    } else {
        removeMessages(category, dossierNr);
    }
}

private void removeMessages(DisBenMessageCategory category, String dossierNr) {
    StringBuilder updateStmt = new StringBuilder();
    updateStmt.append("DELETE FROM DisBenMessage msg ");
    updateStmt.append("WHERE msg.benefitDossier.dossierId = :dossierNr ");
    updateStmt.append("AND msg.category = :category ");

    Query query = em.createQuery(updateStmt.toString());
    query.setParameter("dossierNr", dossierNr);
    query.setParameter("category", category);

    int updateCount = query.executeUpdate();
    LOG.debug("Deleted " + updateCount + " messages.");
}

<persistence-unit name="dmb-jta" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/DisabilityBenefitsDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="be.cm.comps.logman.impl.LogManagerSessionLog"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="Weblogic_10"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        <!--  Global eclipselink Cache -->
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE" />


        <!--  Specific Entities eclipselink Cache -->
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.ContactInfoType" value="Full" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.ContactPointServiceType" value="Full" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.Day" value="Full" />         
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.Federation" value="Full" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.Language" value="Full" />                                

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Can you share your code completely? It's hard to say anything with this code piece.

Comment: done hope it helps to understand, thanks

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable all the breakpoints?

Comment: @farrellmr Indeed when I disable the breakpoints the dossier is well refreshed. There is something lost when the application server has to stop at a breakpoints for too long? Transaction lost? EntityManager doesn't flush? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think its a timing issue - the transaction is happening too fast for the debugger

Comment: @farrellmr and what about in unit testing I also have to refresh it even if i'm not debugging.

Comment: You would have to include your unit test - is it more a integration test?

Comment: Can refer here, similar one might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28695296/366964